# Which bibliography package, style and options does this book use?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I am new to bibtex. I have tried several options such as natbib and apacite, but fail to reproduce the same representation. I mean the same "authors, year; ...", full author list up to 4 people, last name first, position of year, "In ... (eds.)", and volume-colon-pages. Any clues?

> For example, Gerry Tesauro (1992, 1995) combined the algorithm described above ... by a number of researchers (Friston et al., 1994; Barto, 1995a; Houk, Adams, and Barto, 1995).
>
> Barto, A. G. (1995a). Adaptive critics and the basal ganglia. In J. C. Houk, J. L. Davis, and D. G. Beiser (eds.), *Models of Information Processing in the Basal Ganglia*, pp. 215-232. MIT Press, Cambridge, MA.
>   Friston, K. J., Tononi, G., Reeke, G. N., Sporns, O., Edelman, G. M. (1994). Value-dependent selection in the brain: Simulation in a synthetic neural model. *Neuroscience*, 59:229-243.
>   Houk, J. C., Adams, J. L., Barto, A. G. (1995). A model of how the basal ganglia generates and uses neural signals that predict reinforcement. In J. C. Houk, J. L. Davis, and D. G. Beiser (eds.), *Models of Information Processing in the Basal Ganglia*, pp. 249-270. MIT Press, Cambridge, MA.
>   Tesauro, G. J. (1992). Practical issues in temporal difference learning. *Machine Learning*, 8:257-277.
>   Tesauro, G. J. (1995). Temporal difference learning and TD-Gammon. *Communications of the ACM*, 38:58-68.

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  There is the [`custom-bib` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/custom-bib) that will help you build your own style with given features.  Or you can use `biblatex` which has more control over the output.  Why do believe the original uses bibtex?

Comment: @AndrewSwann `biblatex` (or `custom-bib`) looks promising! Thanks! Yes, it may use the more advanced system such as `biblatex`.